# Equivalent of ServerConnection.makeRequest() on python side

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm writing a server extension for jupyter lab and i can use `ServerConnection.makeRequest()` from `@jupyterlab/services` to send POST or GET to my custom URL in typescript.
Now i want to make some request from notebook to this URL by using library `requests` of python but i always get 403 error.

Is there any equivalent of `ServerConnection.makeRequest()` in jupyter lab python library to send request to server ?

Answer (score 1):

Your request from within a notebook is most likely forbidden due to the xsrf check by the jupyter server. When you start jupyter server pass the parameter `--NotebookApp.disable_check_xsrf=True` in the command line to disable it. Or you need to handle passing the xsrf token. Note that disabling this check in an external-facing (production) system is not recommended.

You may also have to pass or suppress token. The token can be suppressed by passing `--NotebookApp.token=''` when you start the server.